# Nodejs Drive v3 doesn't return contents of arrays or objects

Tags: node.js, json, google-drive-api

Using googleapis with node to try to automatically list all files with fields of a target user. initializeDrive handles authorization and works perfectly. In fact it all seams to work except....

```
async function getFiles(){
const drive = initializeDrive("v3");
const params = {
  pageSize: 3,
  fields: 'kind,nextPageToken,files(owners, name,id,thumbnailLink,modifiedTime,permissions)'
};
const res = await drive.files.list(params);
console.log(res.data);
}


getFiles()
```

For some reason any parameter with multiple things returned just shows up as [array] and doesn't return the values.

example:

```
{
      id: '149Lmt-54wgh54h5eshsregreehsrgesh',
      name: 'Untitled document',
      thumbnailLink: 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=149Lmt-149Lmt-54wgh54h5eshsregreehsrgesh&v=1&s=gerafeafewgewaerft',
      modifiedTime: '2020-01-08T21:26:48.899Z',
      owners: [Array],
      permissions: [Array]
}
```

Any idea of how to return the contents of the [Array]?

Comment: Found something called `includePermissionsForView` which is a string parameter. Ref: [Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Comment: In your situation, for example, how about modifying `console.log(res.data);` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data, null, "  "));`? Is this the result you expect?